# Why isn't syntax highlighting on in vim by default?

Tags: vim

I'm just curious.  I've searched around but can't seem to figure out why syntax highlighting isn't on by default in vim.  Yeah, it's simple to add - just add this to your ~/.vimrc file:

```
syntax on
```

It just seems like a no brainer to have this enabled by default?  Does anyone know the history behind why this is how it is?

Comment: Probably historical. Terminal emulation used to be a huge pain in the butt. Also, on older displays, colours were very limited, if available, and things looked like... butt. Nowadays, things might break if defaults change, so defaults rarely change. (And there are also some users that do not like syntax highlighting.)

Comment: subjective, opinion based - vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim is installed by default on your Unix-like machine as a more free, more capable and *more portable* replacement for vi. As such, it is necessary for Vim to model its default behavior as well as possible on vi's original behavior.

And vi didn't have syntax highlighting.

A feature which, while certainly useful, is not necessary *at all* for programming and totally useless for most other uses. One could make the same complaint about line numbers.

The logic is simple: if you are a casual user you get a minimal user experience but you have endless customization possibilities if you are a heavy user.